# re.findall behaves weird

Tags: python, regex

The source string is:

```
# Python 3.4.3
s = r'abc123d, hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
```

and here is my pattern:

```
pattern = r'-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)?|-?\\.[0-9]+'
```

however, `re.search` can give me correct result:

```
m = re.search(pattern, s)
print(m)  # output: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 6), match='123'>
```

`re.findall` just dump out an empty list:

```
L = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(L)  # output: ['', '', '']
```

why can't `re.findall` give me the expected list:

```
['123', '3.1415926']
```

Comment: turn capturing group to non-capturing group.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, um.., if I remove that capturing group, even re.search gives me a None result

Comment: @stribizhev, it's not, '3.1415926' should be a float number in the result

Comment: @O'Skywalker Try to use puttern like -?\d?\.?\d+

Comment: Some online websites could help debug, for example, https://texttoolkit.com/re.findall

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
s = r'abc123d, hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
print re.findall(r'-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|-?\.[0-9]+',s)
```

You dont need to **escape** twice when you are using **raw mode**.

Output:`['123', '3.1415926']`

Also the return type will be a list of **strings**. If you want return type as **integers** and **floats** use `map`

```
import re,ast
s = r'abc123d, hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
print map(ast.literal_eval,re.findall(r'-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|-?\.[0-9]+',s))
```

Output: `[123, 3.1415926]`

Comment: Although this regex is less efficient than mine, I admit the trick with `ast` is cool (although not required in the OP).

Comment: @stribizhev i read one of his comments....`@stribizhev, it's not, '3.1415926' should be a float number in the result` so i included that in my answer :)

Comment: you two are both geniuses, it's difficult for me to choose which one to accept. :)

Comment: You can also reduce the steps using the first character discrimination like this: `(?=[-\d.])-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

Answer (score 34):

There are two things to note here:

- **`re.findall` returns captured texts if the regex pattern contains capturing groups in it**
- the `r'\\.'` part in your pattern matches two consecutive chars, `\` and any char other than a newline.

See [`findall` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Note that **to make `re.findall` return just match values**, you may usually

- remove redundant capturing groups (e.g. `(a(b)c)` -> `abc`)
- convert all capturing groups into [non-capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) (that is, replace `(` with `(?:`) *unless* there are backreferences that refer to the group values in the pattern (then see below)
- use `re.finditer` instead (`[x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, s)]`)

In your case, `findall` returned all captured texts that were empty because you have `\\` within `r''` string literal that tried to match a literal `\`.

To match the numbers, you need to use

```
-?\d*\.?\d+
```

The regex matches:

- `-?` - Optional minus sign
- `\d*` - Optional digits
- `\.?` - Optional decimal separator
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ7pX9/1)

Here is [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/GN4CLB):

```
import re
s = r'abc123d, hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
pattern = r'-?\d*\.?\d+'
L = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(L)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to explain why you think that `search` returned what you want and `findall` didn't?

search return a `SRE_Match` object that hold some information like:

- `string` : attribute contains the string that was passed to search function.
- `re`     : `REGEX` object used in search function.
- `groups()` : list of string captured by the capturing groups inside the `REGEX`.
- `group(index)`: to retrieve the captured string by group using `index > 0`.
- `group(0)` : return the string matched by the `REGEX`.

`search` stops when It found the first mach build the `SRE_Match` Object and returning it, check this code:

```py
import re

s = r'abc123d'
pattern = r'-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|-?\.[0-9]+'
m = re.search(pattern, s)
print(m.string)  # 'abc123d'
print(m.group(0))  # REGEX matched 123
print(m.groups())  # there is only one group in REGEX (\.[0-9]*) will  empy string tgis why it return (None,) 

s = ', hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
m2 = re.search(pattern, s)  # ', hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
print(m2.string)    # abc123d
print(m2.group(0))  # REGEX matched 3.1415926
print(m2.groups())  # the captured group has captured this part '.1415926'
```

`findall` behave differently because it doesn't just stop when It find the first mach it keeps extracting until the end of the text, but if the `REGEX`  contains at least one capturing group the `findall` don't return the matched string but the captured string by the capturing groups:

```
import re
s = r'abc123d , hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
pattern = r'-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|-?\.[0-9]+'
m = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(m)  # ['', '.1415926']
```

the first `element` is return when the first mach was found witch is `'123'` the capturing group captured only `''`, but the second `element` was captured in the second match `'3.1415926'` the capturing group matched this part `'.1415926'`.

If you want to make the `findall` return matched string you should make all capturing groups `()` in your `REGEX` a  non capturing groups`(?:)`:

```
import re
s = r'abc123d , hello 3.1415926, this is my book'
pattern = r'-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|-?\.[0-9]+'
m = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(m)  # ['123', '3.1415926']
```