# Python regex matching only returns one digit when using regex.findall, but matches correctly with regex.search

Tags: python, regex

Here is my idle window right now:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(\d){3,5}')
>>> regex.findall('234234234')
['3', '4']
>>> regex.findall('234 345 456')
['4', '5', '6']
>>>
>>> regex.search('22343')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='22343'>
>>>
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: because of capturing group + re.findall. Try this regex with findall  `regex = re.compile(r'\d{3,5}')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/python-re-findall-behaves-weird. `re.findall` returns a list of captured values if capturing groups are defined. A known issue.