# Regular Expression to recognize a float and pythons findall

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of simple Strings like this one:
`"amount: 134.707625 delay: 180"` and want to extract those 2 numbers, using the following regular expression: `'\d+(\.\d+)?'`
It matches both numbers, but the extraction with findall leads to `['.707625', '']` While the semantically identical regexp `'\d+\.\d+|\d+'` leads to the desired output `['134.707625', '180']`

why do these 2 regexpes behave differently?
Here is my testcode:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\d+(\.\d+)?')
print(pattern.findall("amount: 134.707625 delay: 180"))
print(pattern.match('134.707625'))
print(pattern.match('180'))

pattern2 = re.compile("\d+\.\d+|\d+")
print(pattern2.findall("amount: 134.707625 delay: 180"))
print(pattern2.match('134.707625'))
print(pattern2.match('180'))
```

and here's the corresponding output:

```
> python temp.py
['.707625', '']
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='134.707625'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='180'>
['134.707625', '180']
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='134.707625'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='180'>
```

Im using Python 3.5.2 from the anaconda distribution and Windows 10

Comment: The first one contains a *capturing group* and `re.findall` returns their vaues if they are defined in the pattern. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970). Use non-capturing groups in these cases rather than alternation - `r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?'`

Comment: Alright, thank you