# re.findall() isn't as greedy as expected - Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am attempting to pull a list of complete sentences out of a body of plaintext using a regular expression in python 2.7. For my purposes, it is not important that everything that could be construed as a complete sentence should be in the list, but everything in the list does need to be a complete sentence. Below is the code that will illustrate the issue:

```
import re
text = "Hello World! This is your captain speaking."
sentences = re.findall("[A-Z]\w+(\s+\w+[,;:-]?)*[.!?]", text)
print sentences
```

Per this [regex tester](https://regex101.com/), I should, in theory, be getting a list like this:

```
>>> ["Hello World!", "This is your captain speaking."]
```

But the output I am actually getting is like this:

```
>>> [' World', ' speaking']
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) indicates that the findall searches from left to right and that the * and + operators are handled greedily. Appreciate the help.

Comment: When you use capture groups with re.findall, it returns only the set of captures but not the whole match. Change your capture group `(...)` to a non-capturing group `(?:...)`. *(and the first `\w+` to `\w*`)*. Your problem has nothing to do with greediness.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks a bundle.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/python-re-findall-behaves-weird .  In that question, there was a confounding issue of double escape ``\\`` inside a raw-string.   This question more clearly gets to the heart of a single issue, the behavior of re.findall() when given capturing groups.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that *findall()* is showing just the captured subgroups rather than the full match.  Per the docs for [*re.findall()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group.

It is easy to see what is going on using [*re.finditer()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.finditer) and exploring the [match objects](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#match-objects):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Hello World! This is your captain speaking."

>>> it = re.finditer("[A-Z]\w+(\s+\w+[,;:-]?)*[.!?]", text)

>>> mo = next(it)
>>> mo.group(0)
'Hello World!'
>>> mo.groups()
(' World',)

>>> mo = next(it)
>>> mo.group(0)
'This is your captain speaking.'
>>> mo.groups()
(' speaking',)
```

The solution to your problem is to suppress the subgroups with `?:`.  Then you get the expected results:

```
>>> re.findall("[A-Z]\w+(?:\s+\w+[,;:-]?)*[.!?]", text)
['Hello World!', 'This is your captain speaking.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your regex somewhat:

```
>>> re.findall(r"[A-Z][\w\s]+[!.,;:]", text)
['Hello World!', 'This is your captain speaking.']
```