# python regular expression to split string and get all words is not working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

I'm trying to `split` string using `regular expression` with `python` and get all the matched literals.

RE: `\w+(\.?\w+)*`

this need to capture `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` like stuff only.

[Here is example](http://regexr.com/3gm1d)

but when I try to match and get all the contents from string, it doesn't return proper results.

Code snippet:

```
>>> import re
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pattern = r"\w+(\.?\w+)*"
>>> string = """this is some test string and there are some digits as well that need to be captured as well like 1234567890 and 321 etc. But it should also select _ as well. I'm pretty sure that that RE does exactly the same.
... Oh wait, it also need to filter out the symbols like !@#$%^&*()-+=[]{}.,;:'"`| \(`.`)/
... 
... I guess that's it."""
>>> pprint(re.findall(r"\w+(.?\w+)*", string))
[' etc', ' well', ' same', ' wait', ' like', ' it']
```

it's only returning some of words, but actually it should return all the words, numbers and underscore(s)[as in linked example].

python version: **Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:45)**

Thanks.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r"\w+(?:\.?\w+)*", string)`. If you only need ASCII, pass `re.A` flag so that `\w` only matched ASCII letters and digits. See [demo](https://ideone.com/2sLrjV). If you need to only match letters, replace `\w` with `[^\W\d_]`. Note what you wrote at the beginning is different from what you used in code.

Comment: great, thanks. I've used the same re(`\w+(.?\w+)*`) with `java` and it works fine, can you please point out the difference as well, that will be great.

Comment: Well, you must escape the dot and use a non-capturing group. You do not need the outer capturing parentheses.

Comment: `re.findall('\w+', string)` works as expected, for me.

Comment: thanks a million @WiktorStribiżew, you're awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a **non**-capturing group (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970) why) and escape the dot (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions) what chars should be escaped in regex):

```
>>> import re
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pattern = r"\w+(?:\.?\w+)*"
>>> string = """this is some test string and there are some digits as well that need to be captured as well like 1234567890 and 321 etc. But it should also select _ as well. I'm pretty sure that that RE does exactly the same.
... Oh wait, it also need to filter out the symbols like !@#$%^&*()-+=[]{}.,;:'"`| \(`.`)/
... 
... I guess that's it."""
>>> pprint(re.findall(pattern, string, re.A))
['this', 'is', 'some', 'test', 'string', 'and', 'there', 'are', 'some', 'digits', 'as', 'well', 'that', 'need', 'to', 'be', 'captured', 'as', 'well', 'like', '1234567890', 'and', '321', 'etc', 'But', 'it', 'should', 'also', 'select', '_', 'as', 'well', 'I', 'm', 'pretty', 'sure', 'that', 'that', 'RE', 'does', 'exactly', 'the', 'same', 'Oh', 'wait', 'it', 'also', 'need', 'to', 'filter', 'out', 'the', 'symbols', 'like', 'I', 'guess', 'that', 's', 'it']
```

Also, to only match ASCII letters, digits and `_` you must pass `re.A`  flag.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2sLrjV).