# Remove expressions from string if they are present

Tags: python

I have a problem. I have a string like this:
"Can you please turn off the lights?". Now I want to split the sentence like this:

```
['can', 'you', 'please', 'turn', 'off', 'the', 'lights?']
```

But now I also want to remove the `?` at the end. I know I could just use `substr` but the expressions are not always available. How can I detecet them and if they are present remove them from a sentence?

Here is my code now:

```
given_command = "Can you please turn off the lights?"

data = given_command.lower().split(" ")
print(data)
```

Comment: It may be like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016687/python-regular-expression-to-split-string-and-get-all-words-is-not-working

Comment: use `rstrip("?")` then split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regex) module:

```
import re
given_command = r"Can you please turn off the lights?"
data = given_command.lower().split(" ")
print(list(map(lambda x: re.sub('\\W', '', x), data))) # replace any non alphanumeric character with the empty string
```

Output:

```
['can', 'you', 'please', 'turn', 'off', 'the', 'lights']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `replace`

```
In [98]: given_command = "Can you please turn off the lights?"
    ...:
    ...: data = given_command.lower().replace('?','').split(" ")
    ...:
    ...: print(data)
['can', 'you', 'please', 'turn', 'off', 'the', 'lights']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one symbol to remove (`?`), use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
...
>>> data = given_command.lower().replace('?', '').split(' ')
>>> print(data)
['can', 'you', 'please', 'turn', 'off', 'the', 'lights']
```

If you have more symbols, use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) (I'm using symbols `?`, `!`, `,` and `.` as an example):

```
...
>>> import re
>>> data = re.sub(r'[?!,.]', '', given_command.lower()).split(' ')
>>> print(data)
['can', 'you', 'please', 'turn', 'off', 'the', 'lights']
```

Answer (score 0):

As I referenced a link in comments you can see this one: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016687/python-regular-expression-to-split-string-and-get-all-words-is-not-working)

It will split any mark for you:

```
import re
pattern = r"\w+(?:\.?\w+)*"
re.findall(pattern, 'hello, to world or not?', re.A)
```

result:

```
['hello', 'to', 'world', 'or', 'not']
```