# re.findall returns a string with a single space inside it

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm using regex to find a car plate inside of a given input from a user,

```
numberPlate = input("Enter the Number plate of the car, eg LV04 HNX, HR06PRK")
numberPlateRegEx = re.compile(r'\w\w\d\d( )?\w\w\w') # Creates a regular expression object, can be used to scan strings for anything matching the given pattern, \w is a letter, \d is (strictly, a number or letter), ( )? means there can be an optional space
numberPlateFound = re.findall(numberPlateRegEx, numberPlate)
```

When I enter an input including a pattern including a car number plate then numberPlateFound is a list with a [single space inside of it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVG4J.png)

And when I enter an input [not including a car number plate inside:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AxdJ.png)

This works if i want to just find if something was found, but what If i want to have the found pattern returned? Would I use a different method?

EDIT: My question is [different from this suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/python-re-findall-behaves-weird) as in my example it returns not an empty string, but a string with a space character inside, and I dont know why, I want to know why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/python-re-findall-behaves-weird)

Comment: Concerning the edit: It's still the same issue as shown in the dupe - your pattern contains capturing groups, so findall returns only the captured content. Solution is also the same - use non-capturing groups.

Comment: Change the expression to `r'\w\w\d\d(?: )?\w\w\w'`, `r'\w\w\d\d ?\w\w\w'`, or `r'\w\w\d\d\s?\w\w\w'`

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think i need to look into regex more haha, i understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- No need to put space in its own group to make it optional.
- Without `\b` as my pattern below shows, you may match more than you're trying to.

  - `\b` is a word boundary. It matches anywhere between a word character and non-word character or line start/end: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` without consuming characters (zero-width assertion)
- Using quantifiers as my pattern below shows improves performance

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##HYq9CsIwFEb3PMUlUwKlFCtu4iQUlCIdxCFL0qY2kD9uIyLSZ4/B5XyHjxM/aQm@zdm4GDABakIQjmXrMbhorGZIhRLv724TUwGcirebUJSTtYT07JNGSIuG/uVU0Whl0hDm/zdKrEA/4Xpv9tD1jwq6oTnchgslEY1PDOvZ@Elay1bOc/4B)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"\b\w{2}\d{2} ?\w{3}\b")
s = "Enter the Number plate of the car, eg LV04 HNX, HR06PRK"
print(r.findall(s))
```