# regular expression for matching traceroute output fails

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that match any of the following lines

> localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1)  0.025 ms  0.007 ms  0.006 ms
>
> 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)  0.025 ms  0.007 ms  0.006 ms

I tried the follwing regexp

> [127.0.0.1|localhost.localdomain] (127.0.0.1)  [\d.]+ ms  [\d.]+ ms  [\d.]+ ms

But this doesn't work. It matches only

> n (127.0.0.1)  0.025 ms  0.007 ms  0.006 ms

Can I get some help on this.

Thanks
~S

Answer (score 0):

In character class, there is **no concept** of matching a string. For regex `[cat]`, it does not mean that it should match the word **cat** literally. It means that it should match either **c** or **a** or **t**.

Same case is here. You are trying to match the starting string using character class

```
[127.0.0.1|localhost.localdomain]
```

It should be replaced with **groups** instead

```
(?:127.0.0.1|localhost.localdomain)
```

Also you want to match parenthesis `()` literally, but parenthesis have special meaning in regex. They are **groups**. To match parenthesis literally, it should be escaped using `\`.

So the final regex would be

```
(?:127.0.0.1|localhost.localdomain) \(127.0.0.1\) [\d.]+ ms [\d.]+ ms [\d.]+ ms
```

`(?:)` is non-capturing group. It doesn't store the result in memory.

[**`Regex Demo`**](https://regex101.com/r/9KAIdf/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @user2677279 please do accept the answer if it helps

Comment: I was wonderig in this case, how adding ?: is changing the behaviour or processing. If I don't use ?: , `re.findall` returns only the matched string ( 127.0.0.1 ). If I put ?: it returns the whole string ( 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 0.025 ms 0.007 ms 0.006 ms ). Could you pls let me know why both are different

Comment: @user2677279 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970).