# How do you only capture outermost matches (throw away groups) in python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I apologize if this is a repeated question, but I tried for a while and couldn't figure out what search to use.

Previously, I had a regular expression:

```
example_re = re.compile(r'[\(\[].*?[\)\]]')
```

which was supposed to capture (text that looked like this) and [this], but would also incorrectly capture text that [looked like this).

I fixed it:

```
example_re = re.compile(r'(\(.*?\))|(\[.*?\])')
```

but now, when I call example_re.findall(text), tests are breaking because where the first expression returns a list of strings, the second returns a list of tuples, whenever there is a nested expression [like (this)].

How do I fix this so that findall returns only have the outermost match?

**Edit:** Whoever marked this question as a duplicate really isn't helping anybody. The title of the question that this is supposedly a duplicate of is 'Python re.findall behaves weird'. How was I (or anyone else) supposed to find that? Just by virtue of the fact that I phrased the question differently makes it a non-duplicate.

Comment: Use `re.finditer`. `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\(.*?\)|\[.*?]', s)]`

Comment: So, it is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python, @Blckknght please re-close. Also a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. The linked question is about how to use `findall` in the first place, not about this question's issue about too many capturing groups.

Comment: There are tons of such questions, and there are always 1 answer: either `re.finditer`, or `re.findall` with a non-capturing group.

Comment: The title of the question that this is supposedly a duplicate of is 'Python re.findall behaves weird'. How was I (or anyone else) supposed to find that? Just by virtue of the fact that I phrased the question differently makes it a non-duplicate.

Comment: But thanks, your answer did help

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your pattern so that you don't have two capturing groups. When you have two groups, you'll get a 2-tuple of matching strings, even if one of them is empty.

An easy fix is to make your groups non-capturing, with `(?: )` instead of plain `( )`:

```
example_re = re.compile(r'(?:\(.*?\))|(?:\[.*?\])')
```

Comment: Why do you post a wrong answer to a dupe? `:?` matches 1 or 0 `:` chars. OP does not need it. Pleas re-close.

Comment: The parentheses are important here. `(:? )` is a non-capturing group. It's not the normal `?` in regex.

Comment: You are wrong, non-capturing group syntax is `(?:...)`, [here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970).

Comment: Ah, hell, you're right about the typo. And if the dupe had been to that answer, not the more general one, I probably would have left it closed.

Comment: Please re-close this 1 billionth dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018 explains it all.

Comment: Again, I reopened because this was marked as a dupe of a question that it was not a duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python). No need to jump down my throat over it, after you pulled the dupe trigger too fast. I'll close it as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018 now, since that one is actually applicable.

Comment: Heads up, for fairness. VLQs and duplicates that you've answered in the past are appearing, one after the other, in the deletion queue. Search "user:me deleted:1" to see what answers of yours are being deleted along with them. If you notice you're leaking rep, this is the reason. I also presume that this answer is the cause of the targeted deletion.

Comment: @coldspeed: Um, OK. I don't object to bad questions being deleted, even if I've answered them. But are you telling me about it so I should do something about it (e.g. flag that I'm being singled out or whatever)? I don't care at all about the rep.

Comment: Letting you know since you might have a sentiment similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362016/targeted-closing-of-questions-that-i-answered).