# Trying to use re.findall to capture two different outcomes

Tags: regex, findall

I am trying to use `re.findall` to capture two different outcomes off a webpage.

For example, I want to find both "save $10.00" and "$100.00" if the save exists and if it does not exist then just find the "$100".

I have tried  `save ?\$\d{1,5}`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(?:\bsave\s+)?\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KInjvL/3).

**Details**

- `(?:\bsave\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `\bsave` - whole word `save`
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional  non-capturing group matching

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits

Mind that you need to use [*non-capturing groups*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) to make whole sequences of pattern since [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) only returns (list of) tuples if capturing groups are defined in the pattern and that [causes lots of confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970).