# regex for finding all matches as a single value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to regex expressions in python and trying to find all occurrences of phone nos in a string wherein the country code with a + is not mandatory

```
import re
st="it contains std code +91-888-888-9999 and 777-897-4565"

pattern=r"(\+?\d{2}\-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}"

c=re.findall(pattern,st)
if c is not None:
    print(c)
else:
    print("it is none")
```

If i use search it returns only the first match. Using findall it returns a list with the pattern in the bracket matched as the first value and empty as next

['+91-','']

If a change the pattern to

```
pattern=r"(\+?\d{2}\-)?(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})"
```

i get list of tuples with country code as the first value and phone no as the second value.
Can i get the entire value e.g +91-888-888-9999 as a single unit using search() and findall().
kindly update

Comment: Your `if c is not None:` is pointless. `re.findall` never returns `None`.

Comment: that check i had put when using search. That carried over. It only shows items that we enclose in brackets () and not otherwise. This is not the same as marked duplicate as it is intending to show only () items in pattern whereas our case we need output that is not in the () brackets also in the pattern.

Comment: I don't see how your question is different from the duplicate. That OP has the same problem as you - only the text inside the parentheses () shows up in the result, and they want to change that.

Comment: Can you suggest what regex can we use in this case to get the output desired.

Comment: From [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/1222951): *"convert all capturing groups into non-capturing groups"*: `(?:\+?\d{2}\-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`

Comment: yes, that is what i am looking for. how can i convert the expression in bracket to one without it

Comment: You can't and you don't need to.

Comment: but this is not giving the expected output of the entire phone no with country code as one entry in the return list

Comment: I get `['+91-888-888-9999', '777-897-4565']` as output with that regex. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I am getting [('+91-', '888-888-9999'), ('', '777-897-4565')] on my system with regex (\+?\d{2}\-)?(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})

Comment: I even gave you the regex to copy/paste... come on... For the last time: `(?:\+?\d{2}\-)?\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`

Comment: I missed out. Thanks