# python Regex to match dollar values

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex for dollar value search in Python. I have looked and tried lots of solutions on SO posts, but none of them is quite working.

The regex I came up with is:

```
[Ss]        # OCR will mess up with dollar signs, so I'm specifically looking for S and s as the starting of what I'm looking for
\d+         # any digits to start off
(,\d{3})*   # include comma for thousand splits, can have multiple commas
(.\d{2})?   # include dot and 2 decimals, but only one occurrence of this part
```

I have tried this on the following example:

```
t = "sixteen thousand three hundred and thirty dollars (s16,330.00)"
r = "[Ss]\d+(,\d{3})*(.\d{2})?"

re.findall(pattern=r, string=t)
```

And I got:

```
[(',330', '.00')]
```

Regex doc says that:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
>   groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
>   group. Empty matches are included in the result.

But it is not even getting the whole number part.

My question is: I really want to find `s16,330.00` as a single piece. Is there a solution?

Comment: Remove capture groups: `r = "[Ss]\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?"`

Comment: See all explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove capture groups to allow `findall` to return full matched string:

```
>>> t = "sixteen thousand three hundred and thirty dollars (s16,330.00)"
>>> r = r"[Ss]\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?"
>>> re.findall(pattern=r, string=t)
['s16,330.00']
```

Also note that dot needs to be escaped in your regex

Comment: I think the key was I was missing the "?:", is that for disabling subpattern matching?

Comment: `(?:..)` is called non-capture group. Read more about it: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re

t = "sixteen thousand three hundred and thirty dollars (s16,330.00)"
r = "[Ss]\d+(,\d{3})*(.\d{2})?"

result = [match.group() for match in re.finditer(pattern=r, string=t)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['s16,330.00']
```

The function `finditer` returns an iterator yielding [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). The method group of a match object without arguments returns the whole match.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit on why this will work? I have looked at `finditer` before and didn't know that this will work.

Comment: @YilunZhang Updated the answer!

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but I think anubhava's solution is a more straight forward one :).

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group for the whole pattern, and non-capturing for subpatterns:

```
t = "sixteen thousand three hundred and thirty dollars (s16,330.00)"
re.findall(r"([Ss]\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:.\d{2})?)", t)
['s16,330.00']
```

> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall