# Regex in Python : not able to match repeated group numbers

Tags: python, regex

I use regex to detect numbers from "0" to "999 999 999" inside a string in Python.

```
import re

test_string = "b\'[<span id=\"prl\">114 893</span>]\'"

working_pattern = "\d{1,3}\s\d{3}"
non_working_pattern = "\d{1,3}(\s\d{3}){0,2}"

wk_ptrn = re.findall(working_pattern, test_string)
non_wk_ptrn = re.findall(non_working_pattern, test_string)

print(wk_ptrn)
print(non_wk_ptrn)
```

The results are :

`print(wk_ptrn)` displays : `['114 893']`
`print(non_wk_ptrn)` displays : `[' 893']` (with a space before the first digit)

The non_working_pattern is `"\d{1,3}(\s\d{3}){0,2}"`

```
\d{1,3} :
```

detects 1 to 3 digits [0 to 999]

```
\s\d{3} :
```

detects any white space followed by 3 digits [" 000" to " 999"]

```
{0,2} :
```

is a quantifier so I can detect `"0" (quantifier = 0)` to `"999[ 999][ 999]" (quantifier = 2)`.

I don't understand why `"\d{1,3}(\s\d{3}){0,2}`" doesn't work .
Can you please help me figure out the mistake ?

Thank you. Regards.

Comment: Duplicate of [Python re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/python-re-findall-behaves-weird).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, but you should change it as follows:

```
pattern = "\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3}){0,2}"
```

The `?:` makes the group non-capturing so that [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return the entire matches, and not just the groups. As stated by the linked docs:

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups