# Match a regex to the whole string and not just a part of the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a regex: `r'((\+91|0)?\s?\d{10})'`

I'm trying to match numbers like `+91 1234567890`, `1234567790`, `01234567890`.

These numbers shouldn't be matched: `1234568901112` because it doesn't start with +91 or 0 or doesn't have just 10 numbers:

When I try to use `re.findall()`:

```
re.findall(r'((\+91|0)?\s?\d{10})', '+91 1234567890, 1234567790, 01234567890, 1234568901112')
[('+91 1234567890', '+91'),
 (' 1234567790', ''),
 (' 0123456789', ''),
 (' 1234568901', '')]
```

You can notice that in the third and fourth index the output is not what I want. 
My expected output at third index is 01234568890 and because it starts with 0 and followed by 10 characters. But it's only showing the first 10 characters. Also I don't want the output in the 4th index because it the number doesn't completely match. So either it matched the complete word/string else it is invalid.

Is there any other regex that I can use? Or a function? What am I doing wrong here?

The expected output is:

```
[('+91 1234567890','1234567790', '01234567890']
```

Please let me know if any more clarifications are needed.

Comment: [Use anchors `^` `$`](https://regex101.com/r/0OeJ0R/1)

Comment: @Potatoツ I've tried `^((\+91|0)?\s?\d{10})$` too. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?<!\w)(?:(?:\+91|0)\s?)?\d{10}\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U85XNk/2).

The point is to match these patterns as whole words, the problem is that the first part is optional and one of the optional alteratives starts with a non-word char, so a single `\b` word boundary won't work here.

**Details**

- `(?<!\w)` - there should be no word char immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:(?:\+91|0)\s?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `(?:\+91|0)` -  `+91` or `0`
  - `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `\d{10}\b` - ten digits matches as a whole word, no word chars allowed on both sides

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/KcfQLb):

```
import re
s = '+91 1234567890, 1234567790, 012345678900, 1234568901112, 01234567890'
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\w)(?:(?:\+91|0)\s?)?\d{10}\b', s))
# => ['+91 1234567890', '1234567790', '01234567890']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've made one small change. There was a typo. I've changed 012345678900 to 01234567890 in the input. This should match too.

Comment: @MohitMotwani I updated the post.  I thought about the unambiguous word boundaries (like `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)`) from the very start, but your examples put me off-track.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. `(?<!\w)` This is exactly what I was looking for. Although can you please explain me `?:` more clearly. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @MohitMotwani `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do). It is used here to make sure `re.findall` [does not behave weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970)