# Multiple results when using consecutive patterns regex

Tags: python, regex

```
Test String: "Version 3.1.A"

RegEx: "(\d\.){2}."

Returning: [('1.3.A', '3.')]
```

Why does this return 2 matches, the second only matches a non-reoccuring (\d.)

Is there a way I can force only the complete match (1.3.A) to return using the {*} operator (not explicit \d.\d..)

Comment: Which method are you using? re.match?

Comment: good point, re.findall

Comment: `re.findall(r'(\d\.){2}.', "Version 3.1.A")` gives `['1.']`

Comment: Use a non-capturing group, like this `(?:\d\.){2}.`. `re.findall(r"((?:\d\.){2}.)", "Version 3.1.A")` gives `['3.1.A']`

Comment: @dcg, please add your comment as an answer as thats solved it, cheers!

Comment: I think this is actually a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/re-findall-behaves-weird

Comment: @TheAndyEngineer I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a non-capturing group you can get what you want, like the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "Version 3.1.A"
>>> re.findall(r"((?:\d\.){2}.)", text)
['3.1.A']
```