# re.findall() returning a list of sets

Tags: python, regex

I made a basic regex to find a url:

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|)([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\?\/\=\-\_]*`

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|)` For a subdomain
`([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+` for the hostname
`\.[a-z]+`for the domain
`[a-zA-Z0-9\?\/\=\-\_]*` for the path

When I run this basic program

```
text = "test.google.com test.google.com"
urls = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.|)([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\?\/\=\-\_]*", text)
print(urls)
```

I get this output
`[('test.', 'e'), ('test.', 'e')]`

I assume it has something to do with my regex, but what?
Thanks!

Comment: because re.findall would return all the captured chars when capturing group exists

Comment: You're capturing two groups, so you get a 2-tuple for each of those, and then a list because you're using findall.

Comment: The parentheses denote capture groups ()

Comment: What would I have to add to my regex to fix it?

Comment: You need to put that '+' inside the parenthesis so that all characters are captured (not only 1)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/re-findall-behaves-weird

Answer (score -1):

The parentheses denote capture groups and this is what is getting returned from findall

Answer (score -1):

Because re.findall would return all the captured chars when capturing group exists. Remove the capturing group or turning it to a non-capturing group will return all the matched chars.

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\?\/\=\-\_]*
```

https://regex101.com/r/efXF9D/1/

or

If you want to capture each part separately then you have to use appropriate capturing group for each.

```
(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\.([a-z]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\?\/\=\-\_]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/efXF9D/2/

Comment: Ah! Thank you for your help. I see where I went wrong :)