# Python Regex Match Paragraphs

Tags: python, regex, string, split, findall

I have a String that looks like this:

> ...
>
> Art. 15 Gegenstand Dieses Gesetz regelt die Bekämpfung der
> Geldwäscherei im Sinne von Artikel 305 bis des Strafgesetzbuches6
> (StGB), die Bekämpfung der Terrorismusfinanzierung im Sinne von
> Artikel 260quinquies Absatz 1 StGB und die Sicherstellung der Sorgfalt
> bei Finanzgeschäften.
>
> Art. 22 Geltungsbereich 1 Dieses Gesetz gilt: a. für
> Finanzintermediäre; b. für natürliche und juristische Personen, die
> gewerblich mit Gütern handeln und dabei Bargeld entgegennehmen
> (Händlerinnen und Händler).
>
> ...

I am trying to split the String up into parts from Art. XX to the next Art. XX.

So for Example the first Match should contain the String:

> Art. 15 Gegenstand Dieses Gesetz regelt die Bekämpfung der
> Geldwäscherei im Sinne von Artikel 305 bis des Strafgesetzbuches6
> (StGB), die Bekämpfung der Terrorismusfinanzierung im Sinne von
> Artikel 260quinquies Absatz 1 StGB und die Sicherstellung der Sorgfalt
> bei Finanzgeschäften.

I tried this:

```
x = re.findall(r"Art\. (?s).*(?=Art)",text);
```

and this:

```
x = re.findall(r"Art\. .+(\n.*)*(?=Art)*",text);
```

But it seems not to work as expected...
Also I am not sure wether I should use findall or split.

Comment: Try `r'(?m)^Art\. .+(?:\n(?!Art\.).*)*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when using capturing groups in a pattern and passing it to `re.findall` [only the captures will be present in the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970). Next, you should not try to quantify a lookaround, it makes no sense and is often treated as a user error. `(?=Art)*` here in Python will be treated as if there was no `(?=Art)*`, as it means "there can be `Art` or there can be no `Art`". Same as if there was no lookahead.

You may use

```
result = re.findall(r'(?m)^Art\..*(?:\n(?!Art\.).*)*', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aLcujd/1)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `Art\.` - `Art.` string
- `.*` - rest of the line
- `(?:\n(?!Art\.).*)*` - 0 or more lines that do not start with `Art.`

Comment: what do you mean by "only the captures will be present in the output" and "not try to quantify a lookaround" ?

Comment: @simplesystems See [re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970). `(?=Art)*` is the same as nothing.