# Regular expression only matches start of string

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse the output of a git command with a python script. To that effect, let's say we want to find all the modified and added files in git status, then we would do something like this:

```
import glob
import os
import re
import git

def main():
    g = git.cmd.Git('./')

    layout_pattern = '(modified:|new file:).*'
    matches = re.findall(layout_pattern, g.status())
    print(matches)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, the output from python is truncated:

`['modified:', 'new file:', 'modified:', 'modified:']`

There is an explicit `.*` expression in the pattern, it should match all the way to the end of the line, why isn't it?

Comment: `re.findall` returns only capture groups if any. Use a non-capturing group.

Comment: change `(modified:|new file:)` to a non-capturing group `(?:modified:|new file:)` and you will get the entire match

Comment: What is a non-capturing group?

Comment: Or use `re.finditer`. See all details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970

Comment: `?:` tells the regex engine not to capture the contents of the group it is in. `re.findall` will only return the contents of capturing groups if there are any in the regex, that is why you are just getting `'modified:'` etc. as your result.

Comment: @Nick your solution worked, so if you upgrade it to an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @Makogan I didn't answer because I was expecting the question to be closed as a dupe...