# how to create a regex that matches `change://problem/59689726` and `change://1234567`

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to regex match strings `change://problem/59689726` and `change://1234567`but below code only matches the former,how do I change the regex to match both?how to make `problem/` optional?

INPUT CODE:

```
import re
out = '''
<change://problem/59689726> This is a test1
change://1234567 This is a test2
[Problem]
This is problem desription
'''
m = re.findall("[\S]*(?:change:\/\/problem\/(\d{8,8}))", out.split('[Problem]')[0])
if m:
    for radar in set(m):
        print radar

CURRENT OUTPUT:-
```

59689726

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT:-
```

59689726
1234567

Comment: `1234567` is 7 digits. Is the number length unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get any 1+ digits after `change://problem/` or `change://` you may use

```
re.findall("change://(?:problem/)?(\d+)", out.split('[Problem]')[0])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HUn2X3) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rml4FC/1).

The pattern matches:

- `change://` - a literal string
- `(?:problem/)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of a `problem/` substring
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (what will be returned by `re.findall`): 1+ digits

Comment: where can I understand/read about `(?:problem/)?` ?why we need `?:`

Comment: @user3682248 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970).