# How to use RegEx to find a consecutively repeating string and return a list of matches in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want to know if it's possible to return a list of matches with a regex pattern consisting of a specific, consecutively repeating string, e.g. "ADDD". This may sound trivial, in fact according to regexpal.com, it should be as simple as this "(AGATC)\1+": 
[result in regexpal.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZX7T.png). And using `re.findall`, as stated in the documentation, should return a list with all those matches.
However, when using this code:

```
pattern = r"(AGATC)\\1+"
list_of_results = re.findall(pattern, seq_string)
print("list of results:", list_of_results)
```

where `seq_string` is the string where I'm looking for the pattern and is the same as the one used in the image of regexpal, I get an array of 1 element containing the pattern ('AGATC').

Is it possible to do what I need? Maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: can you post the sample  input and expected output

Comment: @komatiraju033 yes! If you look at the photo, that’s the sample input, and the expected output is a list with the matching string that is highlighted, or strings if there’s more than one. I think it’s easier to understand by seeing the photo, rather than copy pasting the actual string here, since it’d be hard to see where the desired  patterns are inside it.

Comment: You need to define your regex either as `pattern = r"(AGATC)\1+"` or `pattern = "(AGATC)\\1+"`. Use `re.finditer` instead (`[x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, s)]`) (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20search#re.findall) will only return the contents of capture groups if there is one (or more) present in the regex. You can work around this by using an outer group to capture the entire match e.g.:

```
pattern = r"((AGATC)\2+)"
list_of_results = re.findall(pattern, seq_string)
print("list of results:", list_of_results)
```

which will give you a result something like:

```
[('AGATCAGATCAGATC', 'AGATC')]
```

You can use a list comprehension to only return the first value from each result e.g.

```
list_of_results = [g[0] for g in re.findall(pattern, seq_string)]
```

to get something like:

```
['AGATCAGATCAGATC']
```

Or you can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20search#re.finditer) and build your list from the match objects it produces:

```
pattern = r"(AGATC)\1+"
list_of_results = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(pattern, seq_string)]
print("list of results:", list_of_results)
```

which will give you a result like:

```
['AGATCAGATCAGATC']
```

Comment: Thanks! In the first solution, why does \2 works and not \1?

Comment: @JorgePasco that's because the outer group is now group 1, and the inner group (that you want to repeat) is group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

res = re.findall('AGATC', seq_string)
print(res)
```