# Regex: parsing differently if character is escaped

Tags: python, regex

Given this string `"foo-bar=369,337,234,123"`, I'm able to parse it to `['foo-bar', '369', '337', '234', '123]` with this regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\+;]+', 'foo-bar=369,337,234,123')
```

Now, if I escape some of the `,` in the string, e.g. `"foo-bar=369\,337\,234,123"`, I would like it to be parsed a bit differently: `['foo-bar', '369\,337\,234', '123']`. I tried the below regex but it doesn't work:

```
r'[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\+;(\\,)]+'
```

basically trying to add the sequence of characters `\,` to the list of characters to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_+;-]+(?:\\,[a-zA-Z0-9_+;-]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5A2lbc/1/)

If you pass `re.A` or `re.ASCII` to `re.compile`, you may shorten it to

```
[\w+;-]+(?:\\,[\w+;-]+)*
```

**Regex details**

- `[\w+;-]+` - one or more word, `+`, `;` or `-` chars
- `(?:\\,[\w+;-]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of a `\,` substring followed with 1+ word, `+`, `;` or `-` chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/U7oLCU):

```
import re
strings = [r'foo-bar=369,337,234,123', r'foo-bar=369\,337\,234,123']
rx = re.compile(r"[\w+;-]+(?:\\,[\w+;-]+)*", re.A)
for s in strings:
    print(f"Parsing {s}")
    print(rx.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
Parsing foo-bar=369,337,234,123
['foo-bar', '369', '337', '234', '123']
Parsing foo-bar=369\,337\,234,123
['foo-bar', '369\\,337\\,234', '123']
```

Note the double backslashes here, inside string literals, denote a single literal backslash.

Comment: @BiBi I added the regex details.

Comment: I still don't understand why we need to use a non-capturing group `?:`.

Comment: @BiBi See [re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970)