# re.findall -> RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

```
import regex
frase = "text https://www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one other text https://www.gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr"
x = regex.findall(r"/((http[s]?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(gamivo\.com\S*){1})", frase) 
print(x)
```

Result:

```
[('www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one', '', 'www.', 'gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one'), ('www.gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr', '', 'www.', 'gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr')]
```

I want something like:

```
[('https://www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one', 'https://gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr')]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Remove the first `/` and use non-capturing groups. `r'(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?gamivo\.com\S*'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/phCIEr/1).

Comment: do u really need regex for this ? split on spaces and take the ones with https in the resulting array

Comment: @leoOrion yes it's for a more bigger project that needs a regex. So in final project I will replace with str.replace() to use a shorted link

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Remove the initial `/` char that invalidates the match of `https://` / `http://` since `/` appears after `http`
2. Remove unnecessary capturing group and `{1}` quantifier
3. Convert the optional capturing group into a non-capturing one.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/2IIx7C):

```py
import re
frase = "text https://www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one other text https://www.gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr"
print( re.findall(r"(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?gamivo\.com\S*", frase) )
# => ['https://www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one', 'https://www.gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/phCIEr/1/), too. Also, see the related [re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970) post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will take string starting from https to single space or newline.

```
import re
frase = "text https://www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one other text https://www.gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr"
x = re.findall('(https?://(?:[^\s]*))', frase)
print(x)
# ['https://www.gamivo.com/product/sea-of-thieves-pc-xbox-one', 'https://www.gamivo.com/product/fifa-21-origin-eng-pl-cz-tr']
```