# regex to get value and it's proper unit

Tags: python, regex, string

i use the following regex to extract values that appear before certain units:

```
([.\d]+)\s*(?:kg|gr|g)
```

What i want, is to include the unit of that specific value
for example from this string :

```
"some text 5kg another text 3 g more text 11.5gr end"
```

i should be getting :

```
["5kg", "3 g", "11.5gr"]
```

can't wrap my head on how to modify the above expression to get the wanted result.
Thank you.

Comment: Which group are you looking at? Group 0 or group 1?

Comment: You already have the match, see https://regex101.com/r/1IPomV/1 But re.findall returns only the capture group values. See [re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018/re-findall-behaves-weird)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

p = re.compile('(?<!\d|\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*?(?:gr|kg|g)(?!\w)')
print(p.findall("some text 5kg another text 3 g more text 11.5gr end"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTliIQ/1)):

```
(?i)\b\d+\.?\d*\s*(?:kg|gr?)\b
```

- `(?i)` - case insensitive
- `\b` - word boundary

  - `\d+\.?\d*` - match the amount
  - `\s*` - any number of spaces
  - `(?:kg|gr?)` - match `kg`, `g` or `gr`
- `\b` - word boundary

---

```py
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?i)\b\d+\.?\d*\s*(?:kg|gr?)\b")
print(p.findall("some text 5kg another text 3 g more text 11.5gr end"))
```

Prints:

```
['5kg', '3 g', '11.5gr']
```