# How do I extract quotes with regex in python without the quotation marks if I don't know if double or single quotes are used?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract quotes within strings in python with regex. I want to extract quotes within single or double quotation marks and I don't want to extract the quotation marks themselves. In my example below I am able to extract everything I want, but with marks (segments1), or either single or double quotation marks (segments2/segments3), but not everything at once. segments4 returns tuples, and I don't understand why it does that. How do I get my expected output?

This is my code:

```
import re

def extract_strings(query):
  segments1 = re.findall(r'\'[^\']*\'|\"[^\"]*\"', query)
  segments2 = re.findall(r'\"([^\"]*)\"', query)
  segments3 = re.findall(r'\'([^\']*)\'', query)
  segments4 = re.findall(r'\'([^\']*)\'|\"([^\"]*)\"', query)

  print(f'segments1: {segments1}')
  print(f'segments2: {segments2}')
  print(f'segments3: {segments3}')
  print(f'segments4: {segments4}')

print('expected output: \n[\'categorical\', \'data analysis\']\n')

extract_strings('"categorical" yee \'data analysis\'')
```

This is the output:

```
expected output: 
['categorical', 'data analysis']

segments1: ['"categorical"', "'data analysis'"]
segments2: ['categorical']
segments3: ['data analysis']
segments4: [('', 'categorical'), ('data analysis', '')]
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: `re.findall(r'''(?<=')[^']*(?=')|(?<=")[^"]*(?=")''', query)`. *"segments4 returns tuples, and I don't understand why it does that"* - see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31915134/3832970). Actually, it is already all you need, just remove the empty items, or concat them, e.g. `[f"{x.group(1) or ''}{x.group(2) or ''}" for x in re.finditer(r'\'([^\']*)\'|\"([^\"]*)\"', query)]`, see  https://ideone.com/kVIKKs

Comment: `(?<=')[^']*(?=')|(?<=")[^"]*(?=")` is just a bad idea, it returns a wrong result with consecutive quoted parts with the same quotes since the pattern doesn't consume the quotes.