# Python: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe and I try to get string, where on of column contain some string
Df looks like

```
member_id,event_path,event_time,event_duration
30595,"2016-03-30 12:27:33",yandex.ru/,1
30595,"2016-03-30 12:31:42",yandex.ru/,0
30595,"2016-03-30 12:31:43",yandex.ru/search/?lr=10738&msid=22901.25826.1459330364.89548&text=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&suggest_reqid=168542624144922467267026838391360&csg=3381%2C3938%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C0%2C0,0
30595,"2016-03-30 12:31:44",yandex.ru/search/?lr=10738&msid=22901.25826.1459330364.89548&text=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&suggest_reqid=168542624144922467267026838391360&csg=3381%2C3938%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C0%2C0,0
30595,"2016-03-30 12:31:45",yandex.ru/search/?lr=10738&msid=22901.25826.1459330364.89548&text=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&suggest_reqid=168542624144922467267026838391360&csg=3381%2C3938%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C0%2C0,0
30595,"2016-03-30 12:31:46",yandex.ru/search/?lr=10738&msid=22901.25826.1459330364.89548&text=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&suggest_reqid=168542624144922467267026838391360&csg=3381%2C3938%2C2%2C3%2C1%2C0%2C0,0
30595,"2016-03-30 12:31:49",kinogo.co/,1
30595,"2016-03-30 12:32:11",kinogo.co/melodramy/,0
```

And another df with urls

```
url
003\.ru\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_%$#?.:+=|()]+\/mobilnyj_telefon_bq_phoenix
003\.ru\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_%$#?.:+=|()]+\/mobilnyj_telefon_fly_
003\.ru\/sonyxperia
003\.ru\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_%$#?.:+=|()]+\/mobilnye_telefony_smartfony
003\.ru\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_%$#?.:+=|()]+\/mobilnye_telefony_smartfony\/brands5D5Bbr_23
1click\.ru\/sonyxperia
1click\.ru\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_%$#?.:+=|()]+\/chasy-motorola
```

I use

```
urls = pd.read_csv('relevant_url1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
substr = urls.url.values.tolist()
data = pd.read_csv('data_nts2.csv', error_bad_lines=False, chunksize=50000)
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i, df in enumerate(data):
    res = df[df['event_time'].str.contains('|'.join(substr), regex=True)]
```

but it return me

```
UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

At least one of the regex patterns in `urls` must use a capturing group.
`str.contains` only returns True or False for each row in `df['event_time']` --
it does not make use of the capturing group. Thus, the `UserWarning` is alerting you
that the regex uses a capturing group but the match is not used.

If you wish to remove the `UserWarning` you could find and remove the capturing group from the regex pattern(s). They are not shown in the regex patterns you posted, but they must be there in your actual file. Look for parentheses outside of the character classes.

Alternatively, you could suppress this particular UserWarning by putting

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'This pattern has match groups')
```

before the call to `str.contains`.

---

Here is a simple example which demonstrates the problem (and solution):

```
# import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'This pattern has match groups') # uncomment to suppress the UserWarning

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'event_time': ['gouda', 'stilton', 'gruyere']})

urls = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['g(.*)']})   # With a capturing group, there is a UserWarning
# urls = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['g.*']})   # Without a capturing group, there is no UserWarning. Uncommenting this line avoids the UserWarning.

substr = urls.url.values.tolist()
df[df['event_time'].str.contains('|'.join(substr), regex=True)]
```

prints

```
  script.py:10: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  df[df['event_time'].str.contains('|'.join(substr), regex=True)]
```

Removing the capturing group from the regex pattern:

```
urls = pd.DataFrame({'url': ['g.*']})
```

avoids the UserWarning.

Answer (score 69):

The alternative way to get rid of the warning is change the regex so that it is a matching group and not a capturing group. That is the `(?:)` notation.

Thus, if the matching group is `(url1|url2)` it should be replaced by `(?:url1|url2)`.

Comment: Best answer imo.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but changing from `str.contains` to `str.match` did.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) instead. In your code:

```py
res = df[df['event_time'].str.match('|'.join(substr), regex=True)]
```

---

---

## Explanation

The warning is triggered by `str.contains` when the regular expression includes groups, e.g. in the regex `r'foo(bar)'`, the `(bar)` part is considered a group because it is in parenthesis. Therefore you could theoretically extract that from a regex.

However, ***the warning doesn't make sense in the first place***, `contains` is supposed to only "test if pattern or regex is contained within a string of a Series or Index" ([pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)). There is nothing about extracting groups.

In any case, `str.match` does not throw the warning, and currently does almost the same as `str.contains` except that (1) the string must exactly match and (2) one cannot deactivate regex from `str.match` (`str.contains` has a `regex` parameter to deactivate them)

Comment: `str.match('.*'+regex_string)` has the same expected behavior of  `str.contains(regex_string)` with no warning. Only caveat... the `regex_string` shall be a string, not a compiled regular expression.

Comment: This answer worked and the other answers did not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

you should use `re.escape(yourString)` for the string you are passing to contains.

Comment: This could work in very specific cases but is bad advice in the general case. Please expand on which cases it applies to and why escaping work then. Also this has the same effect as passing `regex=False`

Answer (score 6):

Since `regex=True` is provided, `sublist` gets treated as a regex, which in your case contains capturing groups (strings enclosed with parentheses).

You get the warning because if you want to capture something then there is no use of [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (which *returns boolean* depending upon whether the provided pattern is contained within the string or not)

> Obviously, you can suppress the warnings but it's **better** to fix
>   them.

Either escape the parenthesis blocks or use [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) if you really want to capture something.