# DataFrame UserWarning with OR operator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

Python 3.6. I have the DataFrame warning :
`UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.` 
with this pattern :
`laDataTemps.loc[laDataTemps['texte'].str.contains(r'\b(word1|word2)\b', regex=True)]`

Or, if i remove parenthesis to avoid groups, it won't have the same meaning. Any idea on how i could change the pattern to remove the warning ? Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901550/python-userwarning-this-pattern-has-match-groups-to-actually-get-the-groups)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

```
laDataTemps.loc[laDataTemps['texte'].str.contains(r'\b(?:word1|word2)\b', regex=True)]
                                                      ^^^
```

This way, you do not capture any text and keep the semantics of the pattern where word boundaries are applied to both ends of each alternative.

Comment: done, sorry i forgot after waiting for the 5 min delay