# UserWarning: This pattern has match groups

Tags: python, pandas

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\khalha\\Desktop\\RealExcel')
filename = 'sales.csv'

Sales = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
iFlow = Sales.loc[Sales['Product'].str.contains('Vector HF/LF (Opt 2)', 
na=False), "18-Jun"]
print(iFlow)

MaySales = pd.read_csv('maysales.csv')
iFlowmay = MaySales.loc[MaySales['Product'].str.contains('Vector HF/LF (Opt 
2)', na=False), "18-Jun"]
print(iFlowmay)
```

I get the error message:

```
C:\Users\khalha\eclipse-workspace\hariskk\hey\hello.py:8: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  iFlow = Sales.loc[Sales['Product'].str.contains('Vector HF/LF (Opt 2)', na=False), "18-Jun"]
Series([], Name: 18-Jun, dtype: object)
C:\Users\khalha\eclipse-workspace\hariskk\hey\hello.py:12: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  iFlowmay = MaySales.loc[MaySales['Product'].str.contains('Vector HF/LF (Opt 2)', na=False), "18-Jun"]
Series([], Name: 18-Jun, dtype: object)
```

This code works with the first block, but when I add the Maysales portion, it stops working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901550/python-userwarning-this-pattern-has-match-groups-to-actually-get-the-groups)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `str.contains`, you need to escape '(' and ')' in name because they are special chars in regex as follows:

```
iFlowmay = MaySales.loc[MaySales['Product'].str.contains('Vector HF/LF \(Opt 
2\)', na=False), "18-Jun"]
```

Alternatively, you can set `regex=False`

```
iFlowmay = MaySales.loc[MaySales['Product'].str.contains('Vector HF/LF (Opt 
2)', na=False, regex=False), "18-Jun"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Python gets confused when you search for text that includes parenthesis. I can't just run your code since you are importing your dataframe, but I think if you just did:

```
iFlow = Sales.loc[Sales['Product'].str.contains('\Vector HF/LF (Opt 2', na=False), "18-Jun"]
```

it will work

Comment: I get a "error: missing ), unterminated subpattern..." when dropping the closing parenthesis. Adding the \ before the string also throws an error. However, dropping the parentheses all together fixed my related issue. Thank you!